# Выдача прав доступа через power shell

Tags: windows, powershell, доступ, ntfs

Хочу выдать права группе пользователей на определенные папки, в них разорваны наследования.
Я выгрузил все пути в этой папке и хочу дать доступ группе на всё что внутри.
Код ниже, но не могу понять как скормить путь.
Список путей в файле csv в столбце FullName3.
Не могу понять как вытянуть данные из файлы csv.

```
Import-Csv "C:\csv.csv"
$identity = 'domain\Full Acces'
$rights = 'FullControl' 
$inheritance = 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit'
$propagation = 'None'
$type = 'Allow'
$ACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($identity,$rights,$inheritance,$propagation, $type)
$Acl = Get-Acl -Path "\\server\folder"
$Acl.AddAccessRule($ACE)
(Get-Item = $_.FullName3).SetAccessControl($acl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выбрать данные из *.csv:

Исходный файл `c:\test\csv.csv`

```
FullName1,FullName2,FullName3
FIO1,blablabla,c:\test\src\
FIO2,blablabla,c:\test\folder\
```

Код в файле `read_csv.ps1`

```
$table=Import-Csv "c:\test\csv.csv" 
foreach ($row in $table) { 
    $ACL = Get-Acl $row.FullName3
    $ACL | Format-Table
}
```

Вывод

```
    Каталог: C:\test


Path Owner                  Access
---- -----                  ------
src  BUILTIN\Администраторы BUILTIN\Администраторы Allow  FullControl...




    Каталог: C:\test


Path   Owner                  Access
----   -----                  ------
folder BUILTIN\Администраторы BUILTIN\Администраторы Allow  FullControl...
```

[Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Вроде всё написал как надо. Не вытягивает в всё.
`'
$paths=Import-Csv C:\csv3.csv
$cnt = 1
foreach ($path in $paths)
{
"Path {0}:" -f $cnt++
$path.FullName3
$identity = 'domainl\Full Acces'
$rights = 'FullControl' 
$inheritance = 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit'
$propagation = 'None'
$type = 'Allow'
$ACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($identity,$rights,$inheritance,$propagation,$type)
$Acl = Get-Acl "\\server\Folder\"
$Acl.SetAccessRule($ACE)
(Get-Item =).SetAccessControl($acl)
}`'

Comment: Данные извлекаются из csv, просто вы их не используете в коде. Например, у вас `$Acl = Get-Acl "\\server\Folder\"`, а должно, наверное, быть `$ACL = Get-Acl $path.FullName3`

Comment: Переделал пример, сейчас он извлекает из csv реальные пути и распечатывает права доступа к ним